# Create custom add to cart in Wordpress

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a page template with five layers(Support Layer, Comfort Layer, Dimension, Fabric, Final Look), In every layer  am selecting/entering some product details and in 5 layer(Final Look) all the selected detail is coming now i want to pass all the selected properties in Cart How can i do that ??

I am using WooCommerce Plugin for other products but this is custom page template how can i pass selected details in woocommerce add to cart

[image]
Please help me I am not able to understand what should I do now...

Answer (score 0):

Use *woocommerce_add_cart_item_data* and *woocommerce_add_order_item_meta* filters. Wrap all your input fields inside product form( I assume that those tabs are made with javascript so there is no need of reloading the page for each one's content) and set that form's action to add to cart url

Use this in your custom template

```
$product = get_product(77);
echo '<form method="POST" action="' . $product->add_to_cart_url() .'"> elements here, including quantity </form>';
```

Comment: Well... Did it work?

Comment: No man let me update my latest code..

Comment: here is my code can you please take a look    https://codepad.co/snippet/iYzo5bGg

Comment: So you want to add that custom data into session and when you add product to cart take that session data and add it to cart item? In order to run your ajax action, move all your code between lines 24-201 to your theme's functions.php. I would also suggest to group those custom options by product id so that if you make two ajax requests for different products, the values submitted for the second product will override the ones for the first product.

Comment: It's not going on cart page in form actioin i am using your code       action="' . $product->add_to_cart_url() .'"